# addClass() not working in mouseenter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mouseenter function which turns the selected div to have a red color and 1 opacity. I have a class "full" which does just that but when I add that class inside mouseenter, the div doesn't change color. Instead if I add red color and change the opacity inside the mouseenter with this.style.color and this.style.opacity, then it seems to work. My question is why ?

jquery (**NOT WORKING**):

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {

    $( ".content" ).each(function (i) {
        if ( this.style.color != "#F7F7F7" ) {
            this.style.color = "#F7F7F7";
            this.style.opacity = "0.5";
        }
    });

    this.addClass('full');

});
```

jquery(**WORKING**):

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {

    $( ".content" ).each(function (i) {
        if ( this.style.color != "#F7F7F7" ) {
            this.style.color = "#F7F7F7";
            this.style.opacity = "0.5";
        }
    });

    this.style.color = "red";
    this.style.opacity = "1";

});
```

CSS:

```
.full 
{
color: red;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`this` is not a jquery collection in the callback to the `mouseenter` method.  You need to use `$(this)`.

Comment: yes, you are right. Could you explain the difference between `this` and `$(this)`?

Comment: `this` refers to the DOM element, `$(this)` is the DOM element wrapped in a jquery's object, adding jquery methods to it. `addClass()` is a jquery's method, thats why you need to use a jquery object.

Comment: `this` refers to (in this instance) a DOM node. `$(this)` returns a JQuery object based on the node that `this` refers to. A jquery object has all the methods that the $ function has access to. A normal dom node does not.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems; one is that `this` is not a jQuery object in the handler. The other is that your `style` rules will always take precedence over a class*. I don’t really know what the context is, but it seems like you should be making them all that colour by default and adding and removing the class:

```
var $content = $('.content');

$content.mouseenter(function() {
    $content.removeClass('full');
    $(this).addClass('full');
});
```

Although *that* makes it look like your CSS should be less `.full` and more `:hover`, with no JavaScript at all. (And that’s the best kind of JavaScript.)

<sup>* Without `!important`, which you should never use.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`this` should be used like `jQuery(this)`.

Use:

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {

  $( ".content" ).each(function (i) {
    if ( this.style.color != "#F7F7F7" ) {
        this.style.color = "#F7F7F7";
        this.style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
  });

  jQuery(this).addClass('full');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting inline styles with javascript. These will always overrule class styles.